# CSS margin properties don't work with Safari but in other browsers

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, safari, styling

I have a problem with the CSS margin properties in the Safari browser.
On other browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Edge, it works as it is supposed to be, while with Safari it seems that the margin property is getting ignored?

This is the code of the html file:

```
<div class="exercise" [@slideInOutAnimation]="'left'" [@fadeInOutAnimation] *ngIf="question">
<div class="draggableBox" cdkDrag
        (cdkDragEnded)="handleDrop($event)"
        (cdkDragMoved)="handleMove($event)"
        (cdkDragStarted)="handleDragStart()">
</div>

<div *ngFor="let opt of question.options; index as i" class="option" [ngClass]="'direction_' + i"
        [class.active]="isDragging && isDragDirection(i)"
        [class.error]="showError && isDragDirection(i)">
    <ion-icon [name]="'caret-' + directionMapping[i]"></ion-icon>
    {{question.options[i]}}
</div>
```

And this is the code of the CSS file:

```
:host {
display: flex;
flex: 1;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}
.exercise {
display: flex;
flex: 1;
height: 100%;
padding: 20px;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
.draggableBox {
width: 160px;
height: 220px;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
border: 2px solid var(--ion-color-primary);
border-radius: 35px;
z-index: 1;
cursor: grab;
color: white;
}
.option {
position: absolute;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
transition: all 250ms linear;
font-size: 16px;
}
.direction_0 {
margin-right: 275px;
}
.direction_1 {
    margin-bottom: 320px;
}
.direction_2 {
    margin-left: 275px;
}
.direction_3 {
    margin-top: 285px;
}
```

This is how it should look like:

[image: This is how it should look like (Chrome)]

And this is how it looks like with Safari:

[image: This is how it looks like with Safari]

I would be very thankful for your help.

Comment: I might be wrong, but could you try, instead of using margins, use `left`, `right`, etc? I think it might be a bug regarding absolute positioned elements and margins.

Comment: I already tried that, but it is not very reliable. On Safari it works fine, but due to different screen sizes the top label gets a too big margin so it disappears in the top of the screen. Also on bigger screens (desktop) the labels are completely wrong positioned.